# Failing to load SimpleXML on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: php, simplexml, php-7.2, phabricator

I recently installed a phabricator local instance on a Ubuntu 18.04 server, i'm configuring it to use Amazon SES for outbound email, after having configured all the steps mentioned, I'm trying to test the email functionality using `./bin/mail send-test --to` which is failing with the below error:

```
Reading message body from stdin...
[2020-07-10 06:28:19] EXCEPTION: (Exception) The PHP SimpleXML extension is not available, but this extension is required to send mail via Amazon SES, because Amazon SES returns API responses in XML format. Install or enable the SimpleXML extension. at [<phabricator>/externals/amazon-ses/ses.php:84]
arcanist(head=master, ref.master=65cda1596f25), phabricator(head=master, ref.master=205657ac76a2)
  #0 SimpleEmailService::__construct called at [<phabricator>/src/applications/metamta/adapter/PhabricatorMailAmazonSESAdapter.php:62]
  #1 PhabricatorMailAmazonSESAdapter::executeSend called at [<phabricator>/externals/phpmailer/class.phpmailer-lite.php:592]
  #2 PHPMailerLite::Send called at [<phabricator>/src/applications/metamta/adapter/PhabricatorMailAmazonSESAdapter.php:45]
  #3 PhabricatorMailAmazonSESAdapter::sendMessage called at [<phabricator>/src/applications/metamta/storage/PhabricatorMetaMTAMail.php:750]
  #4 PhabricatorMetaMTAMail::sendWithMailers called at [<phabricator>/src/applications/metamta/storage/PhabricatorMetaMTAMail.php:555]
  #5 PhabricatorMetaMTAMail::sendNow called at [<phabricator>/src/applications/metamta/PhabricatorMetaMTAWorker.php:22]
  #6 PhabricatorMetaMTAWorker::doWork called at [<phabricator>/src/infrastructure/daemon/workers/PhabricatorWorker.php:124]
  #7 PhabricatorWorker::executeTask called at [<phabricator>/src/infrastructure/daemon/workers/PhabricatorWorker.php:163]
  #8 PhabricatorWorker::scheduleTask called at [<phabricator>/src/applications/metamta/storage/PhabricatorMetaMTAMail.php:525]
  #9 PhabricatorMetaMTAMail::save called at [<phabricator>/src/applications/metamta/management/PhabricatorMailManagementSendTestWorkflow.php:228]
  #10 PhabricatorMailManagementSendTestWorkflow::execute called at [<arcanist>/src/parser/argument/PhutilArgumentParser.php:492]
  #11 PhutilArgumentParser::parseWorkflowsFull called at [<arcanist>/src/parser/argument/PhutilArgumentParser.php:377]
  #12 PhutilArgumentParser::parseWorkflows called at [<phabricator>/scripts/mail/manage_mail.php:21]
```

I have already installed `php7.2-xml`

My deployment environment is as follows:

```
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

PHP:

```
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.7, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: just for clarifications.. what is your php version?

Comment: @ewong I have mentioned that in the question PHP v7.4

Comment: is php-7.2-xml compatible with php v7.4?

Comment: Can you run phpinfo() and search for SimpleXml? If it isn't you might need to apt-install it.

Comment: @ewong you are right, php-7.2-xml isnt compatible for 7.4, I installed 7.4-xml and it started working! Thanks!

Comment: Hi! If you think this question will be useful for future readers, please consider [answering it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

php-7.2-xml isnt compatible for 7.4, I installed 7.4-xml and it worked!